# auth-hmac functional testing problem 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

I want to use this gem in my api application https://github.com/seangeo/auth-hmac/

I have a question about creating tests for request  authentification.
I want to sign request with hmac but rails controller has no http headers after next code

```
 def setup
    #load from fixture
     @client = clients(:client_2)


 end

 def sign_valid_request(request,client)
    auth_hmac = AuthHMAC.new(client.key => client.secret )
    auth_hmac.sign!(request,client.key)
    request
  end

 def test_response_client_xml

      @request =  sign_valid_request(@request,@client)
      get :index  , :api_client_key => @client.key , :format=> "xml"
      @xml_response = @response.body

      assert_response :success
      assert_select   'id' , @client.id.to_s
end
```

routes has such configuration

```
scope '/:token/' do
     # route only json & xml format
    constraints :format=> /(json|xml)/  do
       resources :clients, :only => [:index]
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with functional testing. To correctly sign each request with AuthHMAC you should put the following in your test_helper.rb

```
def with_hmac_signed_requests(access_key_id, secret, &block)
  unless ActionController::Base < ActionController::Testing
    ActionController::Base.class_eval { include ActionController::Testing }
  end

  @controller.instance_eval %Q(
    alias real_process_with_new_base_test process_with_new_base_test

    def process_with_new_base_test(request, response)
      signature = AuthHMAC.signature(request, "#{secret}")
      request.env['Authorization'] = "AuthHMAC #{access_key_id}:" + signature
      real_process_with_new_base_test(request, response)
    end
  )

  yield

  @controller.instance_eval %Q(
    undef process_with_new_base_test
    alias process_with_new_base_test real_process_with_new_base_test
  )
end
```

then in your functional tests:

```
test "secret_method should be protected by an HMAC signature" do
    with_hmac_signed_requests(key_id, secret) do
      get :protected_method
      assert_response :success
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

```
  def sign_valid_request(request,client)
    auth_hmac = AuthHMAC.new(client.key => client.secret )
    auth_hmac.sign!(request,client.key)
    # because this would be deleted in request.recycle! method in test framework
    request.env.merge!(request.env['action_dispatch.request.parameters'])
    request
  end
```

Line `request.env.merge!(request.env['action_dispatch.request.parameters'])` added here because of Rails 3 test unit framework removes all values from `action_dispatch.request`.

You can find this behaviour here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L404

Comment: you 're right about  request.recycle!
but how can I make full test according to specification ..some request params should go to path as parts of routes, others shouldn't ... for example I should create request path that contains token

Comment: All parameters should be passed as second argument in `get` method: `get :index, {:id => 5, :api_client_key => @client.key, :format=> "xml"}`. So they all would be visible via `params` hash in controller and format type would be applied correctly.

Comment: auth_hmac.sign!(request,client.key) method request must contain predefined path and other parameters to sign request corectly. How can I predefined params that must be a part of path and params that should part of request_uri ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know if it is possible to sign testrequest with AuthHMAC, but it's possible to skip this check at all with gem `mocha`: `ItemsController.any_instance.expects('hmac_authenticated?').returns(true)`. And you can check if AuthHMAC working correctly with offsite consumer. Also you can try integration testing.

Comment: I think now its better not to use hmac_authentification at all in test env..it will be hardcoded but I loose a lot of time for this. Later I'll try integration tests...anyway bounty are yours! If you have something to add I'll be thankfull