# Rails API functional tests with XML body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, httprequest

I've written functional tests for API endpoints built in Rails using shoulda testing framework.

An example looks like the following:

```
  setup do
    authenticated_xml_request('xml-file-name')
    post :new
  end

  should respond_with :success
```

**authenticated_xml_request** is a test helper method that sets
**@request.env['RAW_POST_DATA']** with XML content.

After upgrading the app from **rails 2.3.3** to **rails 2.3.8**, the functional tests are failing because the XML content received is not merged in the params hash.

I'm setting the request with the correct mime type via **@request.accept =
"text/xml"**

I'm able to inspect the content of the request using **request.raw_post** but i'd like to keep the current setup working.

Also, running a test from the terminal using cURL or any other library (rest_http) in development mode, the API works perfectly well.

Any tips or help is much appreciated.

Comment: maybe the similar problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474303/auth-hmac-functional-testing-problem

Comment: Yeah i tried that, but kept getting that `@request.env['action_dispatch.request.parameters']` is `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding a custom patch to rails (test_process.rb file) to convert incoming xml to hash then merge into parameters hash.

on line 439:

`parameters ||= {}`

`parameters.merge!(Hash.from_xml(@request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'])) if @request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] && @request.env['CONTENT_TYPE']=='application/xml'`

Answer (score 1):

Now it's simpler:

```
post "/api/v1/users.xml", user.to_xml, "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/xml'
```

Note that you have to specify appropriate "CONTENT_TYPE". In other case your request will go as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and xml won't be parsed properly.